# Allow RDP or VNC behind an active window, or to a non-input desktop

Tags: c#, .net, rdp, vnc, virtual-desktop

First a little background info on the problem:

My kiosk application must block user access to the computer by putting up a full screen image blocking all windows and the desktop.  Users must not be able to get around this block.  I can easily do this by putting a full-screen window up, OR by creating a new "virtual desktop" and switching to it.  This is the easy part.  Let's call this up front image/window/desktop THE BLOCKER.

What I need help with is allowing a remote desktop user or VNC user to operate the machine behind the BLOCKER, hidden from the user standing in front of the machine.  I do not have a video switch involved (although if there is a cheap one that is remote controllable I might be interested...I need 12 of them).  What I really want is a software solution.

VNC clients only show the current input desktop and do not have the option to ignore certain windows (the BLOCKER), so they don't seem useful for this.  I do not know if RDP allows you to log in to a hidden desktop or if it can operate behind THE BLOCKER.

If anyone knows how this could be accomplished either via commercial software or knows of a software library that does something like this (we use .NET as our dev platform), I would appreciate the help.